# Magento customise PDF and add product attribute data in payment block

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, customize

I want to add the product(configurable) attribute value in payment block

I tried to edit below file

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml

but no luck

Comment: I want to get order items in that phtml file or its block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the core file where payment block is called and I run the order item collection loop and added the configurable options to that block.